How to extract all questions from Stack Overflow?
I want to extract all questions from Stack Overflow. I am trying to download from https://archive.org/download/stackexchange/stackoverflow.com-Posts.7z, but it's updated only until 2019.
I would like to get the questions until today. Anyone know where I can get the updated data? And I would like to get other information about the question too, like authors, accepted answer, etc.
I tried to look at a lot of databases in the internet but I didn't find it.

A single google query of "stackoverflow database download" pointed me to several resources that offer this data for download. You can have a look yourself. If you're having technical difficulties getting something to work with that, ask here. Otherwise, your question seems off-topic.

The item you linked has posts up to this April, they just might not be in any sensible order so it’s hard to tell. The latest download available is up to June, at https://archive.org/details/stackexchange_20240630. If you want newer posts you’ll need to download them through the API, or you can perform queries against a relatively recent version of the data at data.stackexchange.com. A new data dump release should be coming some time in September.

Related: How to create an offline copy of Stack Overflow

Related (meta.SE): How do I download Stack Overflow's data?

Just to note, the link provided by @JeremyBanks is not an official data dump, but provided by a community member.

Stack Overflow controversially changed the way you obtain the Data Dump. Dumps are no longer being uploaded to the Internet Archive and the last official upload was in April 2024 containing data up and including 31 March 2024; Stack Overflow broke their commitment to a July 2024 upload. It is now downloadable from your profile, by going to Settings -> Data Dump Access. From there you can download the data for the site you are currently accessing. Stack Overflow's Data Dump can therefore be found here.
At the time of writing, the current data dump was uploaded on 05 August 2024, however, it is unclear what data that contains (i.e. up to and including 31 July 2024 or up to and including 30 June 2024).

When I try the link above, when i download it, it says that the archive is not available on the site, is there another option?

No, that's where you get the download from now, @GuilhermeHenriqueIchiroSeto . Even on a 1 rep account the link works for me.
